# VMWare Fusion 7: File Not Found

Tags: vmware

I screwed up big time when I tried deleting my Windows 7 VM on VMWare Fusion 7 on my Macbook Air. I put the VM in the Trash and emptied the trash. Now when I try to create a new VM, I get `File Not Found`. I tried moving VMWare Fusion into the Trash so I can uninstall it and then reinstall it but it's not working. How do I fix my problem so I can install a more recent Windows VM? Thank you.

Comment: What did you delete - only the VM image (the one inside the Windows VM package) or the entire Windows VM package ??

Comment: The entire Windows VM package.

Answer (score 8):

Just After installing the new VM you'll get the error "File not found".

1. Click OK.
2. Right-click on the VMware Fusion icon opened in the Dock.
3. Select "Virtual Machine Library".
4. Delete any left-overs from there.

Comment: What a ridiculous place the put the menu item and not in the main app from the top bar.

Comment: digout, it's not the only place. It's also right there in the "Windows" menu of the app. I submitted a suggested edit in this regard to RamaNand's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error – including after deleting a VM (i.e., you cannot do anything inside the VMWare Fusion app to resolve this, as suggested in other answers on this page and at essentially identical questions elsehwere on the site) – I found that the following will work, without reinstalling the app, deleting its preferences, or rebooting the host Mac, but at the tiny cost of having to re-add your VMs to the list of the available ones (a simple drag-and-drop operation):

- Shut down any running VMs that are functioning, then shut down VMWare Fusion.
- Trash the "~/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion/vmInventory" file
- Open the Activity Monitor app, search for "vm", and shut down everything with "vmware", "vmnet", and "vmrest" in its name. (Or do effectively the same thing in the Terminal, with `ps aux | grep vm` and then `kill -9` on each of the appropriate process numbers, if you're command-line-oriented.)
- Go find your VMs in Finder.
- Restart the VMWare Fusion application.
- Drag each of your VM packages to VMWare and drop it on the now-empty left pane of the Virtual Machine Library window to re-add the the VM to the list.
- Test-start each of them to make sure you didn't break anything. [This is the paranoia option, here.]
- Restart VMWare to make darned sure it writes out new config files. [My trust level in this app is quite low of late.]